# LitElement and server side rendering

Tags: node.js, server-side-rendering, web-component, lit-element, lit

I've been trying to make a Web Component with LitElement that works with server side rendering environments (SSR) like NextJS and VueJS, without the need for any janky client-side-only imports. According to Lit's documentation this should be possible, but I keep running into `window is not defined` in NextJS.

What I've got so far is this:

```js
import { render } from '@lit-labs/ssr'
import { TestComponent } from './components/test-component'

const ssrResult = render(TestComponent)

export default ssrResult
```

Apart from adding a couple of hundred kB to the build the `@lit-labs/ssr`-render function seems to do nothing. What I'm trying to achieve, by the way, is not necessarily actual SSR – I'm happy to use any workaround, as long as it's on my end.

The component is structured like this:

```js
import {
  html,
  LitElement,
  TemplateResult
} from 'lit'
import {
  customElement,
  property,
} from 'lit/decorators.js'

@customElement('test-component')
export class TestComponent extends LitElement {

  @property({ type: String })
  public title = ''

  render(): TemplateResult | void {
    return html`
      <div class="content">
        <h3>${this.title}</h3>
      </div>
    `
  }
}
```

Here's my rollup config:

```js
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import filesize from 'rollup-plugin-filesize'
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-polyfill-node'
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'

import pkg from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' }

//Node hack
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
global['__filename'] = __filename

const extensions = ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.mjs']

export default {
  input: './src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'umd',
      name: pkg.name
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es'
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    nodePolyfills(),
    nodeResolve({
      extensions,
      jsnext: true,
      module: true,
    }),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({
      tsconfig: './tsconfig.json'
    }),
    babel({
      extensions,
      exclude: ['./node_modules/**'],
      babelHelpers: 'bundled'
    }),
    filesize(),
    terser(),
  ],
}
```

Comment: Why in the world would you use lit-html when you can just use vanilla template strings?

Comment: Sure, you could always use vanilla, but the actual component I was building at the time had a lot of state and decorators – so Lit saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I seriously doubt that. If you had just used vanilla, you wouldn't even need to mess with Rollup or even learn lit at all, and decorators, what is that? That's not even proper Javascript. Your code example is possibly the most convoluted way I've ever seen to produce HTML. You literally have 13 lines of code just to display a simple div tag. SSR with vanilla javascript (no frameworks) is literally just a string you return from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of `lit@2.3.0` (https://github.com/lit/lit/releases/tag/lit%402.3.0) it is possible to directly import Lit components into a Next.js project without any client only import workarounds. You do not need to use `@lit-labs/ssr` package for that.

So something like below is fine.

```js
// pages/index.tsx

import '../components/test-component';

export default function Home() {
  return <test-component />
}
```

It does not deeply render the custom element's content though, so you'll just get the host custom element tag in the server rendered HTML, though since you mention you're not looking for "actual SSR", perhaps this is all you need.

Once client JS is loaded, the custom element will be upgraded and its contents will render.

You can see an example project here https://github.com/lit/lit/tree/0b35d83ef4f9a72e6520e7a065353c49d44974ac/examples/nextjs

As a side note based on the property you have on your test component, it is best to avoid any global attributes like `title` as a property specifier. https://web.dev/custom-elements-best-practices/#attributes-and-properties

Comment: Thanks! It turns out you're right – on local imports Lit works out of the box. This would indicate that my problem is to do with compiling, I guess. I'll update my question with my rollup configuration!

Comment: Are you using rollup to bundle the Lit component that's being used in a Next.js project? Lit relies on Node's conditional exports for serving different code between server and browser so it shouldn't be bundled into your component code. Best to leave the bundling to the end consumer/application. If you must bundle your component, you should mark `lit` as external so the consumer supplies their own version.